# Theorems are blue, Definitions are yellow, Examples are green,in latex

Tags: color, theorems

I am trying to type my notes. I found many lecture note which uses a different colour for a different environment. Like, theorems are blue, definitions are yellow, etc. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: Should definition-like environments really be typeset in **yellow**? That's going to make them awfully hard to read on most types of paper...

Comment: No, I just mean to ask that how to write in different colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following, which loads the `etoolbox` and `xcolor` packages?

Note that the `yellow` material is rather difficult to notice -- let alone read and understand. Consider using some other color, e.g., `orange` or `magenta`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm} % or: "\usepackage{ntheorem}"
% Set up some theorem-like environments:
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}

\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begingroup\color{blue}}
\AtEndEnvironment{theorem}{\endgroup}
\AtBeginEnvironment{defn}{\begingroup\color{yellow}}
\AtEndEnvironment{defn}{\endgroup}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exmp}{\begingroup\color{green}}
\AtEndEnvironment{exmp}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[When] blu blu blu \end{theorem}
\begin{defn}[What]    bly bly bly \end{defn}
\begin{exmp}[Why]     blg blg blg \end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is no need to `\begingroup` `\endgroup`

Comment: @touhami - Omitting the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements affects -- more precisely: *increases* -- the amount of vertical whitespace that surrounds the theorem-like environments.

Comment: can you think of any why?

Comment: @touhami - Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you doubting my claim that omitting the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` statements affects the vertical spacing? Do I have to supply a reason, or is it good enough to just state a fact?

Comment: I mean do you know why it affects the vertical spacing?

Comment: @touhami - No, I don’t.

Comment: found : *Packages in the graphics bundle* `grfguide.pdf` footnote at page 6.

Comment: @touhami - Very interesting! My hunch (which I'm not in any position to verify) is that it's the first of the two listed causes, *viz.*, the presence of a color-related `\special` whatsit, that's responsible for the additional (vertical) space if there's no explicit `\endgroup`.